# How can I use a different URL instead of a port?

Tags: apache, url, port

I have a server with several services running. One of them is accessible through the domain name like "https://www.foo.bar". Two other services are running on specific ports. So they are accessible through "https://www.foo.bar:1234".
Is it able to configure an apache2 server in a specific way, so it uses always the port 443 but with a different URL like "https://www.foo.bar/service1"?

Answer (score 0):

Try [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse), what you describe is a special case of a setup called *Reverse Proxy*: your httpd forwards requests to the other service and returns the answers to the client. (The other service happens to run on the same machine in your case, but it needn't. A simple kind of backend load-balancing can also be done this way.)

```
<Location /service1>
ProxyPass https://localhost:1234
ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:1234
</Location>
```

Be careful that your other service needs some rudimentary support for this kind of setup: if it returns HTML pages with links in it, it can't assume anymore that `https://www.foo.bar:1234/foo/bar.html` is the correct URL to tell the client. httpd will not look into the returned content and rewrite it for you.